# jquery Pause on Hover slider

Tags: jquery, hover, slider, slideshow

I have a problem with the slider here. I want to pause it when I hover the slider. Unfortunately I do not get the point. Any ideas? Update link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fZYK4/

```
$(function(){
    var slide = $('.productSlide');
    $('.productSlider ul').removeClass('displaynone');

    slide.not(':first').hide();
    $('.productSlider ul a:first').addClass('active');
    $('.productSlider ul a').on('hover', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(false);
        var target = $(this).attr("href");
        $('.productSlider ul a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        slide.not('#'+target).hide();
        $(target).show();
    });
    var counter = 0;
        if( slide.length > 1 ){         
            slide.hide();
            slide.first().show();
            setInterval(function() {
                slide.eq(counter).hide();
                counter++;
                if (counter == slide.length) {
                    counter = 0;
                }
                slide.eq(counter).show();
                $('.productSlider ul a').removeClass('active');
                $('.productSlider ul a').eq(counter).toggleClass('active');
            }, 5000);           
        };
});
```

Comment: submit a jsfiddle.net version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to assign the interval you are setting

```
var counter = 0;
var myInterval;
if ( slide.length > 1 ) {
  slide.hide().first().show();
  myInterval = setInterval(function() {
   // ... and so on
```

and clear it on hover

```
$('.productSlider ul a').on('mouseenter', function(e){
  clearInterval(myInterval);
  // ... and so on
```

If you want to reset if the user hovers out, you best wrap this function:

```
function doAnimation() {
            return setInterval(function() { 
              slide.eq(counter).hide();
              counter++;
              if (counter == slide.length) {
                counter = 0;
              }
              slide.eq(counter).show();
              $('.productSlider ul a').removeClass('active');
              $('.productSlider ul a').eq(counter).toggleClass('active');
            }, 5000);
        }
```

And call it where you want it to start, for example on mouseleave:

```
$('.productSlider ul a').on('mouseleave', function(e){
   myinterval = doAnimation();
```

Comment: wrap the setInterval logic in a function , then do setAnimation(true) and setAnimation(false) to start/stop animation

Comment: looks like splitting hover to mouseenter and mouseleave will render the answer complete, good implementation with returning setInterval ID

Comment: Yes you're right :) I edited the answer. There would be also much more to do, like caching the selectors etc

Comment: What is 'caching selectors' can you give me an example or link? I didnt understand that or may be dont know that :)

Comment: An example would be to cache jQuery DOM selectors used repeatedly so jQuery does not have to scan the DOM every time: var productSliderLinks = $('.productSlider ul a'); productSliderLinks.removeClass('active'); productSliderLinks.toggleClass('thisandthat'); etc.

Comment: great thank you for the term, I use variables to store jQ objects but never used the term 'caching' :)

Comment: There is a great post that uses the term (and has many useful tips :) http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck

Comment: many thanks. Unfortunately, this does not work properly. The animation will not start automatically. Only when I leave '.productSlider ul a'. I have upload this work at fiddle. Thank you for your help. http://jsfiddle.net/fZYK4/

Comment: I made a js fiddle for you here with a working example based on yours: http://jsfiddle.net/QRyce/3/ I included practices I think should be used when writing jQuery, please read the commentaries and links provided. It may seem like a lot to learn at first, but it will help you writing better code in less time. Let me know if there are any questions left!